# How to provide dynamic content pages in react?

Tags: reactjs

After submitting a form I need to display a success page. It's content is determined by the form values and it consists of headline, static text and a form value. In the end 5 different success pages are possible. How can I best provide the data in a separate success page? Do I need 5 different success pages or is there dynamic solution possible?

Routes

```
<Route path="/form" element={<MyForm/>} />
<Route path="/success" element={<SuccessPage/>} />
```

success page templates

```
<h1> Headline A </h1>
<p> Text A <p>
<span> {form value name} </span>

<h1> Headline B </h1>
<p> Text B <p>
<span> {form value name} </span>
```

Comment: Rendering dynamic HTML is a core concept of React. You pass props or use state, then insert the contents into your JSX, using the exact syntax you have in your question. minus the spaces in the variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem.

1. You can put the form values on the query string. Then use that to display content.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// http://localhost:4000/success?valueA=101
const SuccessGenericComponent = () => {
    const search = useLocation().search;
    const valueA = new URLSearchParams(search).get("valueA");
    console.log(valueA); //101
    return (
      <h1> Headline A </h1>
      <p> Text A <p>
      <span> {valueA} </span>
    )
}
```

2. You can use a state management library like Redux, React.Context, or even just your localstorage to handle the state of your form and access it in a different component. This will involve an initial setup though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use generic component for this usecase, as your template data is same, No need for different pages.

You can add conditional rendering to differenciate the page or define a type of page you need from service and display based on that.

Comment: how can I send the name-value to the success page? How does a generic page look like?

Comment: you can send from route data as prop while navigating